Dividing a multiline into equal distances


I am doing a statistical analysis using equal length street segments. I have a multinestring street (Rachel) and id like to segment the multinestring into equal distances. However, I first have to convert it to a line string using the sf package (st_line_sample), which is not suitable for deciding the size of the segment. What suggestions do you have for keeping the geometry as a multinestring so that it can be segmented into equal parts?

Is the problem that there's a junction (bottom left, second image) where the road splits, so the whole feature can't be a single LINESTRING? Or are each of the segments labelled "Rachel" separate features? Or all separate parts of a MULTILINESTRING? Given a set segment length, there's likely to be a bit left over, what do you want to do about that?

Exactly. The whole feature can't be a single linestring because i've removed all roads intersections (I had to do this step because the bike lane linestring doesn't match perfectly the road segments and the intersections were creating problems when I was dissolving the feature into one linestring, well however, because of the missing intersections, it created multilinestrings). So you are right: my end goal would be to create a single linestring based on the road name. I hope this is clearer.

this post seems to be the closest to what I am looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509688/convert-sf-multiline-object-to-evenly-spaced-points

But I'd be nice to have other suggestions

I would approach it with something like: for each linestring endpoint (use lwgeom::st_endpoint()) search for closest linestring startpoint (lwgeom::st_startpoint()), make a linestring between those points and finally union (summarize) all of them. Calculate the total length, divide for given distances...

Okay ill try it! Thanks for the suggestion!
